# Integral of polynomials & $f_k(x) = \begin{cases} 2k& x \in[\frac{-1}{k},\frac{1}{k}] \\ 0&x \in[-1,1]\setminus[\frac{-1}{k},\frac{1}{k}] \end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

Define a sequence of functions as follows: $$f_k(x) = \begin{cases} 2k& x \in[\frac{-1}{k},\frac{1}{k}] \\
0&x \in[-1,1]\setminus[\frac{-1}{k},\frac{1}{k}] \end{cases}$$

Does ${f_k}$ converge in $C[-1,1]$ to a continous function? What can be said about the integrals for g(x) being polynomials $$\int_{-1}^{1}g(x)f_k(x)dx$$ as $k$ approaches infinity?

Attempt:

The function clearly approaches something that looks like a dirac delta function. Since this is unbounded as $k$ approaches infinity, the function does not converge in $C[-1,1]$. My problem is with what can be said about the integrals. All polynomials are bounded on $[-1,1]$ which suggests that all the integrals are bounded as well. At infinity, it seems like the value of the integral will be $4g(0)$. But both these reasoning seems a bit thin. What else can be said about the integrals as $k$ approaches infinity?

Comment: Doesn’t $C$ in $C[-1,1]$ mean “continuous?” Then $f_k$ are not in $C[-1,1].$

Comment: Yes. I guess my roundabout way of saying that was that continous functions on a closed interval will be bounded, but this is clearly not bounded as $k$ infinity, so it will not converge to something in $C[-1,1]$. But of course, it can clearly be seen that $f_k$ is not in $C[-1,1]$

Comment: This is often done instead in $L^2[-1,1].$ Or with triangular functions near $0$.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand why $f_k$ is not in $C[-1,1]$. The main problem for me is what can be said about the integrals

Comment: Or maybe I didn't understood what you meant